# Flutter: Scrollable row, alignment?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to create scrollable row that does not automatically center its items.

As you can see I have a row (that is scrollable via a `SingleChildScrollView`). However, the items are automatically centered by the `SingleChildScrollView`:

[image: row]

I want to be able to customize the alignment of the items to be either on the start or end. My code looks like this:

```dart
  Widget buildHorizontalRow(List entries) {
    var list = <Widget>[];

    for (var entry in entries) {
      list.add(Text(
        entry.name,
      ));
    }

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: list,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Note that when I remove the `SingleChildScrollView` completely, the items start on the left as expected. How do I make them start on the left and scrollable?

---

**Update #1:**

The parents of this row look like this:

```
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 16.0, right: 16.0, bottom: 8.0, top: 8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [....
```

PS: Also please note that I do not want to use a `ListView`.

Comment: Can you include more about its parent widget

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Ahhhh you were right in your assumption, this row is in a `column` and I only needed to set the `crossAxisAlignment` to `start` for it to work 

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Do you want to post an answer or what is the right way to proceed with this question?

Comment: I cant because there is no context about parent widget, you can close others way maybe

Comment: @JosipDomazet did you try using ListView with scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Alright I added the parents. Only thing missing was `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start`. You can go ahead and post your answer. Thanks.

Comment: wish we had close on comment option 

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Ye would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `Column` the default is `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,`, using  `CrossAxisAlignment.start,` solves the issue.

```dart
 Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it working from my side.

```
  Widget buildHorizontalRow(List entries) {
    var list = <Widget>[];

    for (var entry in entries) {
      list.add(Text(
        entry.name,
      ));
    }

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [Row(children:list),Expanded(child:Container(),),]
      ),
    );
  }
```